# Remove Saturdays and Sundays from dates array with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, date, comparison-operators

I am trying to remove weekend days from my jquery array but I get either Saturday or Sunday deleted, never both together.
Can you please check what I am doing wrong?

```
$(dates).each(function( index ) {
    var dt = new Date(dates[index]);
    console.log( index + ": " + dates[index], dt.getDay() );
    if ( dt.getDay() == 0 || dt.getDay() == 6 ) {
        dates.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
console.log(dates);
```

I think that the problem is my "if" statement conditions. but when I try to write two separate blocks, I get same result.

Comment: Modifying the collection you're iterating over requires additional work to "fix" the index. What happens with the "next" element if you remove the "current" element? (and don't use jQuery to iterate over an array of dates...)

Comment: I would suggest using a form of a filter on the dates.  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to filter instead.

```js
var weekdaysOnly = dates.filter(function(element, index){
    var dt = new Date(element);
    console.log( index + ": " + element, dt.getDay() );

    //not saturday or sunday
    return (dt.getDay() != 0 && dt.getDay() != 6);
});

console.log(weekdaysOnly);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very better than trying to remove from the array

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing value from original date array, try saving it in a temp array. This is because if you remove value from original date array, it will result error in looping.

```
var date_tmp = [];
$(dates).each(function( index ) {
    var dt = new Date(dates[index]);
    console.log( index + ": " + dates[index], dt.getDay() );
    if ( dt.getDay() != 0 && dt.getDay() != 6 ) {
        date_tmp.push(dates[index]);
    }
});
console.log(date_tmp);
```

Comment: It works also. I should have thought about the temporary variable. Thanks